# Buttons not working when Dart project is moved to server

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm a math teacher with some novice Java skills. About six years ago I made some applets so my students could practice word problems. As time went on, more and more of my students have had problems using the applets because of browser incompatibility (I think). So this summer I've been working to convert the applets into a Dart app. The entire project is two `textarea`s and about eight `button`s that either display a problem or its solution.

So far I've got it working just fine in Dart Editor. It compiled to JavaScript without an error or warning and runs well in JavaScript, also through Dart Editor.

I copied the files to my website using FileZilla, but when I access the app on the server via a browser (I tried Safari and Internet Explorer) the app looks correct but none of the buttons work. That is, nothing happens when they are clicked. I'm not sure that I have copied all of the correct files/folders.  I copied everything to the server that is within the `web/` directory. There are two HTML files, one in `out/` and one in `web/`. Which HTML file should it launch from? And should I just rename that file to `index.html`?

I've got about 40+ hours on the Dart phase of the project but am about out of time to devote to this particular problem. I've put in a few hours searching for help and related examples online, but I think my questions are so basic that there is no information available.

Again, I'm not a web developer or programmer. Think 50 year old math teacher.

Answer (score 5):

Since a Dart project contains symlinks to dependencies, you can't simply copy a project to a server and have it work. `pub deploy` is a command that bakes your application and bundles the files for copying to a server.

It's somewhat a early, but there's a description here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13y7yCwq9GtPChXtd6t0YMcUtMJLZq2IVwq546Dve_No/edit

Comment: I ran pub deploy from the pubspec.yaml file/window in the dart editor, then uploaded everything in the "deploy" directory to the server.  I ran the app from the html file in the "web" directory.  Worked Great!!  Many Thanks!!  Woot Woot!!

Comment: To add context, I'm guessing that you were missing dart.js from the browser package. That comes in from pub, and is symlinked. When you tried to copy and deploy your app, I'm wondering if the files from packages were left behind. Yay for pub deploy!